# How to pair values of one column against index or categories of other column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to pair values of a specific column using pandas and group-by method against a specified index (Start). My dataset is:

```
     Start  Times
     Chicago    2
     Detroit    0
     Minnesota  3
     New York   1
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Start      Int      Time Pairs
Chicago   Detroit   [2,0]
Detroit   Minnesota [0,3]
Minnesota New York  [3,1]
```

Is this possible please and how can I do it?

Comment: What is the criterion for pairing values?

Comment: The different locations have a unique travel ID - By the time pairs, I should be able to get the frequency (count) of the same travel ID. I can get my code to work by creating bins eg. [0,5] , [5,10] ref. Time Column, however that's not the counts (frequency) I'm after. Ideally I want to get my dataset sorted as the second attachment so I can continue with the code and get a proper count  of travel ID between each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one using [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) in order to concatenate a shifted versions of the `Series`:

```
df_ = (df.Start.astype(str)
               .shift(1)
               .str.cat(df.Start.astype(str), sep=',')[1:]
               .str.split(',', expand=True))
df_.columns = ['Start', 'Int']
df_['Time Pairs'] = (df.Times.astype(str).shift(1)
                             .str.cat(df.Times.astype(str))[1:]
                             .apply(list))
```

---

```
     Start        Int     Time Pairs
1    Chicago    Detroit     [2, 0]
2    Detroit  Minnesota     [0, 3]
3  Minnesota    NewYork     [3, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll trial the answer now and come back to you ASAP.

Comment: Superb solution!! Now I can get all applicable combinations and time pairs. Thanks ever so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Although not that clear the criterion of pairinig values (shifting rows?), this is a (rough) way to get the result:

```
dftot = pd.DataFrame({'Start':df.Start[:-1].values,
                      'Int': df.Start[1:].values,
                      'Time Pairs' : [[i,j] for i,j in zip(df['Times'][:-1].values,df['Times'][1:].values)]})
```

**output**

```
dftot

    Start     Int       Time Pairs
0   Chicago   Detroit   [2, 0]
1   Detroit   Minnesota [0, 3]
2   Minnesota New York  [3, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solution has worked brilliantly as well!